# Windows Bash - Emacs build fail: Memory Protection Enabled

Tags: windows, bash, emacs, win-bash

I am trying to compile emacs-24.4 within Windows Bash (WinBash? Win-Bash?) however running into a problem that windows seems to have memory protection enabled which breaks the emacs build.

The error I get after 'make' (./configure works fine) is:

```
Dumping under the name emacs
**************************************************
Warning: Your system has a gap between BSS and the
heap (25164600 bytes).  This usually means that exec-shield
or something similar is in effect.  The dump may
fail because of this.  See the section about
exec-shield in etc/PROBLEMS for more information.
**************************************************
/bin/bash: line 7:  6853 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./temacs --batch --load loadup bootstrap
make[1]: *** [bootstrap-emacs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tdwyer/bin/emacs-24.5_linux_build/src'
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

In the etc/PROBLEMS file, the relevant section gives:

```
*** Segfault during `make bootstrap' under the Linux kernel.

In Red Hat Linux kernels, "Exec-shield" functionality is enabled by
default, which creates a different memory layout that can break the
emacs dumper.  Emacs tries to handle this at build time, but if this
fails, the following instructions may be useful.

Exec-shield is enabled on your system if

    cat /proc/sys/kernel/exec-shield

prints a value other than 0.  (Please read your system documentation
for more details on Exec-shield and associated commands.)

Additionally, Linux kernel versions since 2.6.12 randomize the virtual
address space of a process by default.  If this feature is enabled on
your system, then

   cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space

prints a value other than 0.

When these features are enabled, building Emacs may segfault during
the execution of this command:

    ./temacs --batch --load loadup [dump|bootstrap]

To work around this problem, you can temporarily disable these
features while building Emacs.  You can do so using the following
commands (as root).  Remember to re-enable them when you are done,
by echoing the original values back to the files.

    echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/exec-shield
    echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space

Or, on x86, you can try using the `setarch' command when running
temacs, like this:

    setarch i386 -R ./temacs --batch --load loadup [dump|bootstrap]

or

    setarch i386 -R make

(The -R option disables address space randomization.)
```

And, unsurprisingly, if I look to see if it is enabled .. it is:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
2
```

But unfortunately, I try to disable it (even running bash as administrator), it fails:

```
$ sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
bash: /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space: Permission denied
```

Furthermore, setarch doesn't work using:

```
setarch x86_84 -R make
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Is this on [win-bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net) or WSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the instructions at: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/318315/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization

Important part:

> to disable it, run
>
> ```
> echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
> ```
>
> and to enable it again, run
>
> ```
> echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
> ```